# Is there a way to add attributes to coverity snapshots to allow filtering

Tags: coverity

I'm new to Coverity.  I would like to be able to mark snapshots with a tag like "RC1" to allow filtering in Coverity Connect.  I can select cids that are in snapshots by a date or date range or a snapshot ID.

I'd like to be able to automatically add tags (known to our build system) as each snapshot is created, programattically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

In cov-commit-defects you can specify

```
--description "description"
--target <platform>
--version <version>
```

and you can filter against those values in the Snapshot views.  However, you can't filter with those attributes in the Issues:By Snapshot view.